# How to install packages?

Tags: packages, deployment

This is always a problem when I distribute my packages to colleagues working on different platforms. I have my packages installed into a private directory and I autoload some of them when *Mathematica* starts, but since everyone has a different folder hierarchy and different customs on where to put files/what to autoload, this is always a bottleneck. Should non-power-users simply use the menu option: `Install...`? Can a foolproof script be defined, that - no matter what platform is in use - installs these packages in a way that both the user and both *Mathematica* (and the code I wrote and distributed) can find it? That is, packages are not added to the system-default package directory. Or would it be better to put packages into the default directory of *Mathematica* (e.g. `C:\Applications\Mathematica 8.0.1\AddOns`)? If yes, then which directory should hold them: `LegacyPackages`, `ExtraPackages` or `Packages`?

**Further questions:**

What if the package that I send consists of multiple packages, in a delicate directory structure? Can the menuitem `Install...` deal with that?

Comment: I never looked at the install option before, I've always done it by hand.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Note:** *This answer was originally written with package authors in mind, aiming to provide a **user-friendly** way to distribute packages and provide installation instructions. If your aim is user convenience, today [you should be using paclets instead](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250314/12).*

---

I think that the menu item `File -> Install...` is very convenient, even for power users.  The only problem is that there is no uninstall option.  However, if the package consists of a single file, upgrading is easy: the old file will be overwritten with the new file.

You can write some simple instructions for users:

1. Open the .m file you sent them
2. Choose `File -> Install...`
3. Choose Type -> Package, Source -> (the open notebook), Install Name -> SomePackage
4. Load the package by evaluating `` <<SomePackage` `` .

The only thing that can go wrong is that they mistype the install name.

The `Install...` menu item will put the package into

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

which on Windows is

```
%appdata%\Mathematica\Applications
```

(Press <kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> and type the above to get to that directory.)

When necessary, the package file can be deleted from that directory.

This is the usual way I install and upgrade palettes myself.

---

Putting packages into the Mathematica installation directory is not really advantageous because they will get lost when Mathematica is upgraded (for example, from 8.0.1 to 8.0.4).  Instead they can be put into `$BaseDirectory/Application` (for all users) or `$UserBaseDirectory/Application` (for the current user).  This is what the `Install...` menu item does.

---

It seems that the `Install...` menu item can deal with multi-file packages too.  "Type of Item to Install" should be set to "Applications", "Source" -> "From File..." and the package files need to be inside an archive (.zip file).  I have not used this personally, so I have no experience with it (e.g. about what happens on upgrade).

---

@AlbertRetey noted below that the [Wolfram Player Pro](http://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/) does not have this menu item at all.  The only way to install packages into it is to do it manually or create a script that does it.

Comment: See edit in original post about multifile packages. Thanks for clearing up what exactly the `Install...` does. It was sort of a black box up till now.

Comment: @István Edited, seems possible, but I have no experience with this ...

Comment: @István Thinking about it, for packages it really doesn't make a big difference.  For palettes, using Install... is pretty convenient because palettes are commonly generated (they don't come from a file).

Comment: There is another thing that might or might not be a problem: the PlayerPro is missing the File -> Install menu. You will need to write a script that installs as Leonid has suggested if you want to deploy to PlayerPro.

Comment: @Albert Good point, I was not aware of that

Comment: Is there a programmatic way (instead of using the File Menu)?

Comment: @Sterling Why are you asking? If you want to write your own package, look into [paclets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131101/12). That is the future, and installation is a simple `PacletInstall[]`. Please, please do not hack together your own custom installer! I've seen so many of those break or misbehave (in fact I don't know if I've seen any that never breaks ...)

Comment: @Sterling If you are a user, then follow the installation instructions of the package you are dealing with. There is no single way that works for all packages. Older packages that attempt to follow standard are installed in the way Leonid describes. Newer packages _should_ use paclets (and therefore the programmatic way is `PacletInstall`), but often they don't.  If the package has a fragile custom installer, consider complaining to its author.

Answer (score 18):

One very simple option: install all packages into

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

It is trivial to write a script which will do that, and this is a platform-independent way of specifying a directory which always exists, and where Mathematica will always look for packages.

As an alternative, you can give the user a choice of a directory, and append it to the `$Path` variable.

I would not recommend putting packages into system folders such as `AddOns`, for many reasons. One is that there can be many users on the machine with a single installation of Mathematica, and if you put it into a system folder, all of them will experience its presence there, whether they want it or not (and whether *you* want it or not).

Comment: +1 everything *user* should be in `$UserBaseDirectory` for easy management.  Copy system files to this directory as needed, duplicating the tree, if you need to modify them.

Comment: Also, packages in the system folder will get lost on upgrade (from e.g. 8.0.1 to 8.0.4)

Comment: Note that the BaseDirectory and UserBaseDirectory locations can be changed by adding respectively MATHEMATICA_BASE or MATHEMATICA_USERBASE environement variables containing their new path to the system. For doing this in Ubuntu see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5994031/884752. In Windows its in the system settings.

Comment: To all: I can tell you that anything in the $UserBaseDirectory (if left as default) can get lost when reinstalling Windows. Therefore, I have a very strong feeling against putting my stuff into whatever directory the OS offers.

Comment: @Istvan Well, *a lot* can get lost when reinstalling Windows.

Comment: @Leonid: Nothing gets lost if kept at a safe place out of the installer's path, preferably on an other drive :)

Answer (score 6):

If you found this question while looking for user-friendly ways to distribute your own package, **you should look into using paclets**:

- [How to distribute Mathematica packages as paclets?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131101/12)

Using paclets is the future:

- Packages come as a single `.paclet` file.
- They can be installed with the convenient [`PacletInstall`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PacletInstall.html) command, and uninstalled with [`PacletUninstall`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PacletUninstall.html).
- Paclets can contain metadata about which Mathematica versions and which platforms they are compatible with, eliminating the problem where people inadvertently try to use a package on an incompatible system.

There is currently absolutely no reason not to use the paclet format for distributing any Mathematica package. Compatibility is not a concern. While the paclet system became documented only in Mathematica 12.1, most of its features work in Mathematica 10.0, or even earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks Szabolcs for the update. Do you think I should accept this answer (being the most relevant in modern times) or should I leave it as is, for those still looking explicitly for package installation?

Comment: @IstvánZachar This QA is useful both for package developer and package users. This answer is aimed mostly at package developers, and the accepted answer already has a link here. I think it's fine if we keep things as they are, but in the end it's up to you.