# Packages problems on version 9 under OS X

Tags: packages

Using Version 9 on OS X, I've run into some problems with creating packages and accessing them.  I've done the following:

- wrote all the function definitions in a notebook and tested that they all worked;
- created a package of the definitions.
- used `Install` to place the package in the `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]` directory;

For good measure I rebooted my computer and restarted Mathematica.

Attempting to load the package gives me nothing, so I simplified everything to see if I'd still have a problem.  I made a very simple package:

```
BeginPackage["testPackage`"]
f::usage = "f[x] returns 2x"
Begin["`Private`"]
f[x_] := 2 x
End[ ]
EndPackage[ ]
```

I saved and installed it as I described above.  Still nothing.

```
<< testPackage`
Names["testPackage`*"]

{}
```

I have also tried each of the following:

```
Get["testPackage`"] (* Doesn't appear to do anything or get any response from Mma *)

Get[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "testPackage`"}]]
$Failed

Needs["testPackage`"]
Needs::nocont: Context testPackage` was not created when Needs was evaluated. >>
```

Nothing works.

You can see the package installed in the ...Mathematica/Applications directory:

[image: directory]

I followed (or at least thought I followed) the recommendations in [How to install packages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-to-install-packages)

I thought doing so would place the package in a path known to the front end.

What have I missed?

Comment: The package is ok. Is the directory in your `$Path`? Try `Get["testPackage.m", 
 Path -> FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]]`.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen -- Tried your suggestion. It doesn't work either.  Starting to look like a mystery.

Comment: Maybe Install put it somewhere else. How about copying your package file directly to `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]`.

Comment: Oops ... old posts coming back to haunt me!  Does `Get[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "testPackage.m"}]]` work?  Note that I changed ``testPackage` `` to `testPackage.m`.

Comment: Also, you installed into `$UserBaseDirectory`, i.e. choose "Install for this user only", correct?  I repeated the exact steps you describe (as far as I can tell), and it works correctly here.  The question is what we did differently.

Comment: If ``Get["testPackage`"]`` gives no response that typically indicates success, but you're saying that `f` is still not defined after this?

Comment: @Szabolcs -- Get[FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "testPackage.m"}]] doesn't work.  re: $UserBaseDirectory, yes I install for "this user only".  And I also thought no response meant success but f does not show or evaluate as defined.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen -- I can see the package in the designated directory: /Users/jagra/Library/Mathematica/Applications

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're creating a package using a notebook (with `AutoGeneratedPackage -> Automatic`) you need to write all your code in "Initialization Cells".  Everything else is commented out.

Comment: Terry -- That nailed it.  Everything works.  Funny because I've poured through the package documentation today and I don't remember any mention of initialization cells.  Thx.

Comment: I used to create packages with WorkBench and I don't remember needing to initialize cells.

Answer (score 6):

Do not put your code directly in the `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` folder. Rather, create a new folder in the `Applications` folder, `MyTestApplication` say. Then write your `BeginPackage` statement as:

```
BeginPackage["MyTestApplication`testPackage`"]
```

Load the package with:

```
<< MyTestApplication`testPackage`
```

Or, create a `Kernel` folder in the `MyTestApplication` folder and create an `init.m` file in the `Kernel` folder that contains the above `Get` statement. Then you can load the package with:

```
<< MyTestApplication`
```

*Mathematica* will execute the `init.m` file and load the package. You could even have multiple packages and have the `init.m` file load each of them.

Users seem to constantly stumble over where to put packages. Create an application within the `Applications` folder and put the package THERE. That's where *Mathematica* looks for them.

#### Adding a little more discussion:

It would help if users thought a little less about "Packages" and a little more about "Applications". An application is a folder where you can collect your work on some topic: a book you are studying, or a course you are taking, or a research and development project. Where do you put your application folder? In the *Mathematica* `$UserBaseDirector/Applications` folder - where else? Your application folder might or might not contain package files. It may contain many notebooks. It may contain a whole folder structure. If you write packages, which is fairly easy to do, you could also add documentation through Workbench. It is a great way to organize, preserve, document and communicate your work. It is the fruit of your labor.

So, most of all, create those applications folders for your various projects.

Comment: +1 especially for the insight into thinking in applications.  Thx