# How to install custom package

Tags: packages

There is [great code by István Zachar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/how-to-manipulate-2d-plots) , but I do not know how to use it. I have saved the code as a .m file and use file->install to install it. However, when I call the package the error message below occurred. May you so kind to give me some reference of how the package to be created and install from scratch. I really want to write some useful package by myself.

```
Needs["ExploreGraphics`"] 

Needs::nocont: Context ExploreGraphics` was not created when Needs was evaluated.
```

Comment: Check the variable `$Path`.  Is the package file in one of the directories listed?

Comment: Yes, the package file is in the folder.

Comment: Kuba♦ Thank you. I saved the code by  István Zachar in a m.file with name ExploreGraphics.m and use ExploreGraphics as the name of package. I am not sure whether it is the right way to use the code.

Comment: @Kuba Thans for reminding me the cross-post this in Wolfram community. I had write to the moderation team for apology and will make sure the infomration will always be added next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the content of the message is only about missing context, which is usually introduced by `` BeginPackage["ExploreGraphics`"] ``. Your functions should already be loaded.

If your package is on `$Path`, and it seems it is, otherwise you'd get additional `` Get::noopen: Cannot open ExploreGraphics`. `` message, you are almost there.

If you want it to work well with `Needs` you need to add mentioned `BeginPackage` and friends. See [Creating Mathematica packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29324/5478), shortly you should write something like:

```
BeginPackage["ExploreGraphics`"]

  GetPlotRange::usage = ...
  GraphicsButton::usage = ...
  ...

Begin["`Private`"]
   (*implementation*)
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

Further reading:

[How to install packages?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/669/5478)

Comment: Thank @Kuba♦ very much. I finally got why the funtion in the package are loaded. I use an .nb file to test the code and save it as .m file. Now I copy the code into a new .wl file ( created by file->new->package(.wl) ) and save it as .wl file. Then I install the .wl file the same way with file->install. Fortunately all function work well now. I am wondering whether there is a way to develop package diractly from .nb file. http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/297046 give a hint that one can set AutoGeneratedPackage ->Automatic to achive it, but I had hard time to find the option.