# Problem while installing a custom package (RGTC)

Tags: packages, installation

I am using

"11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"

and I am trying to install the RGTC package, which can be found here.

[Download the package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/200528/1871)

Then following the answer given by Szabolcs here [How to Install packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-to-install-packages)

after I unzip the folder, I opened the EDCRGTCcode.m and then did the following

Choose File -> Install...
Choose Type -> Package, Source -> (the open notebook), Install Name -> (i used the exact same name that the notebook has)

Then, I tried to load the package by evaluating

<< EDCRGTCcode.m`

but I get the following error

```
During evaluation of In[4]:= Get::noopen: Cannot open EDCRGTCcode.m`.

$Failed
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does ``<< EDCRGTCcode` `` work? Without .m.

Comment: It returns this SetDelayed::write: Tag Classify in Classify[x_] is Protected.

Comment: That is expected because it was written before `Classify` existed in ``System` `` context. So it will interfere.

Comment: This package also does ``Unprotect["Global`*"];ClearAll["Global`*"];Remove["Global`*"];`` so I think it needs a little love to make it more robust.

Comment: @Kuba you are right. I am running some of the examples and it seems that it is working. can you explain a bit more on the situation? Thank you for your comments and the help.

Comment: @Konstantinos the packages looks to be unavailable now.

Comment: @resanrom I have not tried to use it in a while and I have no idea what happened.

Comment: Well, I think this question should be closed because the failure is caused by a simple mistake? As pointed out by @kuba , the code for loading the package should be `<< EDCRGTCcode\`` rather than `<< EDCRGTCcode.m\``.

Answer (score -2):

place that .m file in "/Applications/Mathematica/AddOns/AutoLoad" 
this directory.

Comment: can you explain why anyone should do that?

Comment: I am afraid this answer is incorrect. It is generally a bad idea to modify the installation directory. Also, the directory you reference does not exist. There is indeed an `Autoload` (not `AutoLoad`) directory, but it is not located at this path. In most cases, it may not be the best idea to set up packages to auto-load.

Comment: Normally, packages go into `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications`. To find out what `$UserBaseDirectory` is, simply evaluate it in Mathematica.

Comment: for mathematica to load a custom made package it should be placed in the directory so that it can use the resources.
you are not interfering with any other packages you are just telling it to load the custom made package.

Comment: Autoload or AutoLoad I don't think so if it will make any difference until the directory at the specified path. If it is not there you can always create it.