# Where can I find the package RGTC?

Tags: packages, physics

I am unable to find the package RGTC which is the prerequisite for the package Surface Charges that I require. All places I searched for only provide [one download link](http://www.inp.demokritos.gr/%E2%88%BCsbonano/RGTC/) which gives Error 404. Can I substitute this with some other package or can I find the package elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is [this](https://faculty.washington.edu/lgy/ph564/) what you're looking for?  If so, someone should mirror it for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

Updated links, which have been crawled by Wayback Machine: [RGTC Code](https://web.archive.org/web/20190203214700/http://depts.washington.edu/ph506/EDCRGTCcode.m) and [RGTC Documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190323103538/http://depts.washington.edu/ph506/RGTC.nb)