# Where I can find RGTC package? (2021 version)

Tags: packages, physics, tensors

I am not being able to find the RGTC package for Mac. I followed the instructions of this [Mathematica Stack Exchange answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200529), however, the documentation notebook says "Not Found".

Comment: This seems an inappropriate venue for this question. Have you tried contacting the author of the package?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4484/

Comment: Here's another link that you can load via `Get`: https://faculty.washington.edu/lgy/ph564/EDCRGTCcode.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says not found because it is incorrectly linked in https://faculty.washington.edu/lgy/ph564/

(The link https://faculty.washington.edu/lgy/ph564/RGTC.m does not work.)

Actually, the correct link is https://faculty.washington.edu/lgy/ph564/RGTC.nb