# Running file with some extension

Tags: packages

I want to run the Mathematica file with some extension, like '.m'. But, I don't know, how can I run the code. Please, guide me.

Comment: Have a look at `Get`.

Comment: To keep it simple, pass the full path to the file to the `Get` function. That's all.

Comment: what is ''Get''? There is no link. I can't open this.                                               How can I pass the full path to the file? Can you help me Please? I have Mathematica 11.3 in my system. But, not able to run the code in file with extension ''.m''.

Comment: Please help me. Actually I don't know about packages. So, I am facing difficulties.

Comment: Actually, corresponding with OP and checking the `*.m` file, it is clear from the contents of the file that it is not generated by *Mathematica*, and is not of Wolfram syntax (hence the close vote). Perhaps the `*.m` file is from Matlab, as I recall its vector syntax being `[v1, v2, ...]` that complies with said file.

Answer (score 2):

If a file has the extension `.m`, then I assume you are trying to load a package into your notebook. This can be achieved by calling the package (say called PackageName.m) into your own notebook by doing the following:

1. You can type into your opening like `` <<PackageName` ``, which uses the backtick symbol `` ` ``. It is probably at the left hand side of your keyboard.
2. Alternatively, this is a shortcut for the MMA function `Get`, given in the [documentation here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html). The first example has the above notation I was talking about. Then `Get["PackageName.m"]` would work.

Here is a screenshot so you can see the backtick in action.

[image: Click on this to take you to my image.]

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response.                                                        
Are you talking about this symbol '' ~ ''.  I just type  "<<PackageName(~)" in the notebook, but it does not work. I also type ''<<~'', it also does not work. Sorry to say, I am facing difficulty to learn from the example.

Comment: I have added a screenshot. You are on the right key I think, but instead you have held-down shift instead. It's a tricky key to type, but my screenshot should help you.

Comment: It's tricky but: enclose any code that has backticks in double backticks. I did this for your answer.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive that's one of the worst things that to look at - 5 backticks is far too many. Thanks for your help JM.

Comment: Now, I followed your suggestions and type. But, I found the error. I am pasting here both input and output which I got.     In[8]:= <<PackageName`
Get["PackageName.m"]

During evaluation of In[8]:= Get::noopen: Cannot open PackageName`.

Out[8]= $Failed

During evaluation of In[8]:= Get::noopen: Cannot open PackageName.m.

Out[9]= $Failed

Comment: @MisbahShahzadi - unless you've called your package `PackageName` then Mathematica won't find it. You need to search for your own package name which you have on your system. A key point is to make sure that the package is installed in the correct directory. This either could come with a file distributed with your package, which will automatically install it in the correct location, or you'll need to do it manually. A buzzword might be `$UserBaseDirectory`. This post may be useful: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-to-install-packages

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried with the same procedure as mentioned in the link but  get syntax error. How can I paste here screen shot?, so you can see the error.

Comment: Screenshots aren't much use. If you have to, post your screenshot and more importantly, your code as an edit in your original post.