# Loading a missing package in studymaterial

Tags: packages, compatibility

A notebook needs a package : `` Needs["Algebra`ReIm`"] ``

Got it retrieved the package : `` Algebra`ReIm` ``  Legacy Standard Add-On Package.

Installed via file-install in MMA.

The package name is Relm.m

The package is not loadable with : `` Needs["Algebra`ReIm`"] ``

Question: is this command `Needs` correct ?

Comment: You don't say where you put `ReIm.m`.  Your `Needs` command has to match the location of the package.

Comment: Use single "`" and no space in the name. Try: Neeeds["Algebra`ReIm"] if you stored the packages in a subfolder named Algebra

Comment: @Daniel Huber ,  

 I see here folder AddOns containing 3 folders with packages in them
The installation of the package ReIm via MMA and install was not quite clear: give the name and location installed package where it will be installed ?

Comment: @Bill Watts  
Where the package will be installed via install in MMA is not yet known to me.

Comment: Needs["Algebra ReIm"] gives error :
Needs::cxt: Invalid context specified at position 1 in Needs[Algebra ReIm]. A context must consist of valid symbol names separated by and ending with `.

Comment: `Needs["Algebra`ReIm`"]` is this the correct one?
Get::noopen: Cannot open Algebra`ReIm`.
Needs::nocont: Context Algebra`ReIm` was not created when Needs was evaluated.

Comment: Note: the backquote(tick?) is not shown here in Needs, but in notebook present
How are the packages organized?
( what is a standard package) 
Suppose you also want to create your own package.

Comment: @janhardo you can use double backticks to enclose code when your code itself contains backticks. See the edits I made to your question for an example. ``Needs[Algebra`ReIm`]`` is entered as \`\`Needs[Algebra\`ReIm\`]\`\`. Alternatively you can escape the backticks in your code using \\` which also works (`Needs[Algebra\`ReIm\`]`).

Comment: @MarcoB,  Thanks for solving this backtick issue.
Unfortunately no progress yet in getting the package working

Comment: I am digging in this forum about package installing, so it looks i am close to get it working
[installing packages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/669/how-to-install-packages)

Comment: Which version do you have? In MMA version 13.0 ReIm is built in and need not be loaded.

Comment: @ Daniel Huber its version 12.3 i am using

Comment: @janhardo `ReIm` has been built in to MMA since version 10. Are you sure that you need to load a package to achieve what you want? What functionality are you seeking?

Comment: @ MarcoB  The package is used in a class series of complex analysis
Then i must find the package back somewhere at
- %appdata%\Mathematica\Applications
- or in  the Mathematica folder in Program Files on Windows under Application folder

Comment: If `Needs[Algebra`ReIm`]`  is a Algebra folder ?  within ReIM  enclosed in Applications folder te be found: it is not there.

Comment: Aha.. i get a message now after installed the ReIm package in a folder Algebra in the Applications folder : 
General::obspkg: Algebra`ReIm` is now obsolete. The legacy version being loaded may conflict with current functionality. See the Compatibility Guide for updating information.

Comment: It does not work yet a number of packages from 2006 in this notebook
When I open the package ReIm it only says:
BeginPackage["Algebra`ReIm`"]

(*ReIm::obslt =
"The ReIm package is obsolete. Use instead functionality provided by
Assuming, ComplexExpand, Refine, and similar functions.";*)

EndPackage[]


Do need the package because it works/needed in the 2006 lesson series
How to get this package ?

Comment: You can find it here https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/6759/.  Since the functionality of `ReIm` is now included, the package that is calling it may be to old to run in modern versions of Mathematica.  You could also try commenting out the request for `ReIm` from the package you are trying to run.

Comment: @Bill Watts  If I cannot use some packages in the 2006 study material , then unfortunately the study material has become worthless.
To translate these failed packages to modern packages in the study materials is going to be a tough job, because I am not an experienced MMA user (though instructive, that is).
There are even more non-working packages to be found in the study material.
One way or another I have to get it working and maybe the old packages from 2006 are still to be found somewhere ?
If they are too old the 2006 packages for the current MMA version?

Comment: It's a common problem with old notebooks.  You might check to see if the author has updated study materials.

Comment: The study material was downloaded from the publisher and there seems to be no further support from the author , as his website references are no longer there.
I will make an inventory of which packages are missing and maybe it is not so bad that few do not work.
I have now opened the notebook for complex functions and there are a few packages missing.
I can try to fix the not working commands with the help of the forum here.

Comment: What _study material_ are you refering to?

Comment: [studymaterial](https://www.cambridge.org/au/academic/subjects/mathematics/real-and-complex-analysis/complex-analysis-mathematica?format=AR)
You could download it also.

Comment: It is funny to see that the author encrypted some files of CD-ROM, but whatever. Passwords are here https://web.archive.org/web/20150905192850/http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~shaww/web_page/books/complex/index.html and here is the update https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6870/ and here are bigger files https://web.archive.org/web/20150908013457/http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~shaww/web_page/books/complex/V6withoutput/

Comment: @ Валерий Заподовников
Thanks! , you've picked that out nicely from this study material
Well done!
I am curious to see if I can improve the current study material with your info

Comment: Does the studymaterial has more files? Can you upload cambridge link somewhere else, it is restricted?